# Insert URLs in plaintext after each hyperlink in MS Word using VBA

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, hyperlink, visual-basic

I would like to automatically insert the URL for each hyperlink in a word document beside the linked text.

For example instead of having:
[my hyperlinked text](https://google.ca)

It should be:
[my hyperlinked text](https://google.ca) (https://www.google.ca)

Here is some code I started in VBA which replaces all links with their address beside them but this removes the original hyperlink. Is there anyway to keep the hyperlink while appending the URL beside it in brackets?

```
Dim oLink As Hyperlink
Dim strText As String
Dim strLink As String
For Each oLink In ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks
    Let strText = oLink.Range.Text
    Let strLink = oLink.Range.Hyperlinks(1).Address
    Let oLink.Range.Text = strText & " (" & strLink & ")"
Next oLink
Set oLink = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
Sub processhyperlinks1()
Dim i As Long
Dim oLink As Word.Hyperlink
Dim r As Word.Range
Dim s As String

For Each oLink In ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks
  Set r = oLink.Range
  r.Collapse WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
  s = oLink.Address
  ' optional
  If oLink.SubAddress <> "" Then
    s = s & "#" & oLink.SubAddress
  End If
  r.Text = " (" & s & ")"
  Set r = Nothing  Set r1 = Nothing

Next
End Sub
```

If you want to colour the link text blue, you would need to modify the font of the range or perhaps apply the relevant Hyperlink character style.

If you want both the old link and the new thing to be hyperlinks, you could start with something like this:

```
Sub processHyperlinks2()
Dim i As Long
Dim r1 As Range
Dim r2 As Range
Dim s As String
i = 1
With ActiveDocument
  Do Until i > .Hyperlinks.Count
    Set r1 = .Hyperlinks(i).Range
    Set r2 = r1.Duplicate
    r2.Collapse WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
    r2.Text = " ()"
    r2.Start = r2.Start + 2
    r2.End = r2.Start
    r2.FormattedText = r1.FormattedText
    s = .Hyperlinks(i).Address
    ' optionally include any SubAddress.
    If .Hyperlinks(i).SubAddress <> "" Then
      s = s & "#" & .Hyperlinks(i).SubAddress
    End If
    r2.Fields(1).Result.Text = s
    Set r2 = Nothing
    Set r1 = Nothing
    i = i + 2
  Loop
End With
End Sub
```

(When you are adding the type of object that you are iterating, you have to be careful to avoid an infinite loop, and sometimes working backwards using e.g. For i = .Hyperlinks.Count to 1 Step -1 may not work either).

If you want to ensure that Hyperlinks entered via the Dialog box ended up with this layout, you would probably need to write your own UserForm to do the parts of the standard one that you need. (This userform isn't one of the older WordBasic ones that would let you extract the different values such as Address, SubAddress, DisplayText etc. easily).

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code I wrote a while back:

```
Sub HyperLinkExpand()
    ' Charles Kenyon
    ' 16 July 2018
    ' Add text of hyperlink address to text display or substitute address for text
    ' response to question on Answers forum https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/subject/forum/category/topic/cc65005f-b4cd-4173-8756-85d17f02c7a1
    '
    Dim oLink  As Hyperlink
    Dim strAddress As String
    Dim strLink As String
    '
    For Each oLink In ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks
        Let strAddress = oLink.Address
        Let strLink = oLink.TextToDisplay
        Let oLink.TextToDisplay = strLink & " (" & strAddress & ")"    'add url in parentheses to hyperlink
        '        oLink.TextToDisplay = strAddress ' replace text in hyperlink with url
    Next oLink
End Sub
```