# Change text color of URL in Word VBA

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

After the URL is displayed beside the hyperlink, the formatting from the hyperlink is applied. Is there a way to remove the blue, bolding and underline formatting for the URL.

Current format:

[My hyperlinked text](https://google.ca) ([www.google.ca](https://google.ca))

Intended format

[My hyperlinked text](https://google.ca) (www..google.ca)

```
Dim oLink As Hyperlink
Dim strText As String
Dim strLink As String
For Each oLink In ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks
    Let strText = oLink.Range.Text
    Let strLink = oLink.Range.Hyperlinks(1).Address
    oLink.Range.InsertAfter " (" & strLink & ")"
Next oLink
Set oLink = Nothing
```

Comment: The first piece of code in my Answer to your previous question should insert the display text without the hyperlink formatting.

Comment: Here is the prior thread:Q https://superuser.com/questions/1777431/insert-urls-in-plaintext-after-each-hyperlink-in-ms-word-using-vba

Answer (score 0):

### You can change the character styles that are automatically applied.

The styles are Hyperlink and Followed Hyperlink. These are applied to all hyperlink fields by default.

To be clear, you want to change these styles so they no longer have the color or underline features. Again, these styles are automatically applied to a hyperlink in Word. Even if you change the color and underlining in the text, once a hyperlink is used, the Followed Hyperlink style will then be applied.